# SQL UPDATE syntax error

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to update some data within a table in ms-access using vb.net. However I am getting an error when trying to run the code. My Query is:

`Query = "UPDATE tabDatafiveMinutely SET PAR0050=308.3925 WHERE TimeValue = #16 May 2012 14:30:00#"`

The error I get is:

`No value given for one or more required parameters.`

Does anyone have anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

EDIT:

The Syntax is Correct I had a problem with the Database

Comment: This error means that some field names, specified in query, are not present in table (or are reserved words).

Comment: The column wasn't present in the table (I was looking in the wrong database). If you make this an answer I will give you an accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Promoted to answer as requested* :)

This error means that some field names, specified in query, are not present in table (or are reserved words).

Answer (score 1):

just dont make use of `#` instead of that us `'` might resole your issue

```
UPDATE tabDatafiveMinutely SET PAR0050=308.3925 
  WHERE TimeValue = '16 May 2012 14:30:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
Query = "UPDATE tabDatafiveMinutely SET PAR0050=308.3925 
         WHERE TimeValue = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-05-16', 102)
```

for other date format

```
Date -100- MMM DD YYYY' -- Feb 5 2010
Date -101- MM/DDYYYY'
Date -102- YYYY.MM.DD'
Date -103- DD/MM/YYYY'
Date -104- DD.MM.YYYY'
Date -105- DD-MM-YYYY'
Date -106- DD MMM YYYY' --ex: 03 Jan 2007
Date -107- MMM DD,YYYY' --ex: Jan 03, 2007
Date -108- MMM DD YYYY' -- Feb 5 2010
Date -110- MM-DD-YYYY' --02-05-2010
Date -111- YYYY/MM/DD'
Date -112- YYYYMMDD' -- 20100205
Date -113- DD MMM YYYY' -- 05 Feb 2010
```

to convert date to text use like this

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),113)
```

Comment: I will save this, I use a function to convert `Date` to a `string`. `DateTime.ToLongDateString & " " & DateTime.ToLongTimeString` which works correctly for me.

Answer (score 0):

The date must be between quotes, I think:

```
Query = "UPDATE tabDatafiveMinutely SET PAR0050=308.3925 WHERE TimeValue = '#16 May 2012 14:30:00#'"
```